# how can i implement loading bunch of images in my android app

Tags: android

i am trying to implement an application which load bunch of images (Like Google images loading ) from server.by using which concept i can implement this,i tried google didn't find a solution give me good suggestions and any examples or links thank you in advance.

Comment: Do search about UniversalImagedownloader, Lazyloading of images etc..

Comment: TQ Pragnani it is useful.& sorry i dont hav points to up vote 4 u r ans

Comment: Good to know it is useful for you...

Answer (score 0):

Use a listview or gridview to display images.

Inflate your custom layout and display images in a listview or gridview.

You can use https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader Universal Image Loader to load images either form MediaStore or from the web. Uses caching. Based on Lazy Loading but has more configuration options.

In you adapter contructor

```
 File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(a, "UniversalImageLoader/Cache");


// Get singletone instance of ImageLoader
imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
// Create configuration for ImageLoader (all options are optional)
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(a)
          // You can pass your own memory cache implementation
         .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
         .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
         .enableLogging()
         .build();

// Initialize ImageLoader with created configuration. Do it once.
imageLoader.init(config);
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
.showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_id)//dummy image
.cacheInMemory()
.cacheOnDisc()
.displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
.build();
```

In your getView()

```
  ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageview); 
  imageLoader.displayImage(imageurl, image,options);
```

You can also use https://github.com/thest1/LazyList. Also uses caching.

Also use a ViewHolder in listview or grdiview. http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html.

For Endless list you can use commonware endless list. https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless.